# JSF 1.2 issue on commandButton

Tags: jsf, monitor, managed

JSF 1.2 CommandButton not Working

```
<h:dataTable first="0" rows ="#{aptMgmtUIHandler.usocsOnFirstPanel}"
value="#{aptMgmtUIHandler.appt.usocList}" cellspacing = "3" var="usoc">
<h:column>
<h:outputText value="#{usoc.displayName}"></h:outputText>
<h:outputLabel value=":"></h:outputLabel>
</h:column>                                 
<h:column rendered="#{usoc.displayName eq 'Ethernet Tech Install (1CRMM)'}">            
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{usoc.usocQuantity}" style="height:22px"
rendered="#{usoc.booleanType}">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="NO" itemValue="#{aptMgmtUIHandler.no}" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="YES" itemValue="#{aptMgmtUIHandler.yes}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:inputText value="#{usoc.usocQuantity}" style="height:17px"
rendered="#{!usoc.booleanType}"
onchange="return isNumeric(this.value, '#{usoc.displayName}')">
</h:inputText>
</h:column>

<h:column rendered="#{usoc.displayName ne 'Ethernet Tech Install (1CRMM)'}">            
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{usoc.usocQuantity}" style="height:22px"
rendered="#{usoc.booleanType}" >
<f:selectItem itemLabel="NO" itemValue="#{aptMgmtUIHandler.no}" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="YES" itemValue="#{aptMgmtUIHandler.yes}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:inputText value="#{usoc.usocQuantity}" style="height:17px"
rendered="#{!usoc.booleanType}"
onchange="return isNumeric(this.value, '#{usoc.displayName}')">
</h:inputText>
</h:column>

</h:dataTable>

<h:commandButton id="nextAdd" value="Next" styleClass="button" 
action="#{aptMgmtUIHandler.getCalendarFromCTS}"></h:commandButton>
```

My Bean Scope in xml is session. After clicking on the button its not calling the backbean method.
Its not showing any Error message. After removing the render its calling the method.

Comment: "After removing the render its calling the method." - so is it working with the xml you posted or not?

Comment: Please search the possible causes here: [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2118656/1065197)

Comment: Did you place the code inside "h:form" tag?